How to manage user session in WebSocket
I'm developing a WebSocket server in Go where I read messages from clients and forward them to a tunnel. I want to integrate session management:

Check if a user's session is still valid.
Handle session expiration and revocation and extend it, closing connections when necessary.

I'm looking for guidance on implementing these session management features within the context of this WebSocket server. We are cloud service and multiple WebSocket connections for each user is possible, so nicely managing this is important. What are the best practices for handling sessions, expiration, and renewal in this scenario? Are there any examples or patterns in Go that could help with this? We are using Redis for our sessions, so accessing the session via Redis is possible. We are using refresh tokens to refresh users sessions (without access token).
And for WebSocket, it's just a basic loop to check users messages and handle them accordingly:
for {
    ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(20 * time.Second))
    _, message, err := ws.ReadMessage()

    if err != nil {
        handleDisconnection(err, session, tunnel)
        return
    }

    if _, err = tunnel.WriteAndFlush(message); err != nil {
        handleTunnelError(err, session)
        return
    }
}

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

That depends on what exactly those WebSockets do. What is the protocol. If it is a request response pattern, then you can simply add a token to each request. Similarly to how HTTP works. It's the simplest solution. And if your protocol is not a request response, then I suggest you actually make it a request response. You will thank me later.

@freakish what is a request/response websocket? you mean like normal API calls?

WebSocket is just a transport protocol. To make it meaningful you need some other protocol on top of it. For example you send a request frame and then wait for a response frame. What exactly that means is up to you. These can be for example jsonrpc. Or even nested HTTP, why not. Either way request response pattern simplifies everything. Regardless of details.

@freakish ok i have no idea what is that, we just used the basic gorilla/websocket package and did not config the transport protocol. So the websockets are actually for creating a web page with data of sth like RDP or SSH connection, so user and the actual servers are going to be busy all the time and write and read messages. what transport protocol do you think is better for this?

What to do depends on your requirements. Often it's sufficient to check auth once when opening the connection, and then permit access for as long as it remains open. In other cases, you might want to check that the user remains authorized before handling each WS message. But running this check on every message could add latency, and running it every N seconds or every N messages would introduce jitter. This may or may not be acceptable for your performance requirements (probably unacceptable for RDP). In more complicated cases, you might want to monitor the session in a background goroutine.

@amon that was my first thought, to start a go routine with ticker to run every 5-10 seconds and check if session is still valid, and if not then disconnect the Webscoket. But is there any other ways to handle Websockets sessions overall? I did not find anything on internet.
